# How to receive data in Activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am getting boolean value either true or false according to my use case in my BroadcastReceiver. Then I am broadcasting that value to my activity. below is my code

```
boolean flag12 = MtpClient.isUSBDevice(usbDevice);
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
Intent i = new Intent("broadCastName");                 
intent.putExtra("MYMTP",flag12);
mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

How to receive this in activity. Is I have to create one more broadcast in my activity ?. Because I am doing sendBroadcast in same activity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getBoolean()` in your activity

```
Boolean yourBool = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("MYMTP");
```